# Docstring for predetermined dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, docstring

I wanted to create a proper docstring for my logging module.

When creating the logger object, I provide several parameters to it. Two dictionaries and one string. Those dictionaries partially only allow a few accepted strings as values.

```
smooLogger = logging_handler.logger(
    stream_logger={"active": True, "level": "debug"},
    file_logger={
        "active": True,
        "level": "debug",
        "fname": "output",
        "mode": "a",
    },
    logger_name="smooLogger",
)
```

I am not sure, how to properly reflect that in the docstring. I am following the numpy syntax. So far I have come up with this, but I don't know if this is correct.

```
def logger(
    stream_logger=dict(),
    file_logger=dict(),
    logger_name="",
) -> logging.Logger:
    """
    Description

    Parameters
    ----------
    stream_logger : dict
        dict of {bool : str}
        Accepted Values: {True, False : "debug", "info", "warning", "error", "critical"}
    file_logger : dict
        dict of {bool : str : str: str}
        Accepted Values: {True, False : "debug", "info", "warning", "error", "critical" :
        "filename without file extension" : "a", w"}
    logger_name : str, optional, default ""
        String that will be used as the name of the logger object.

    Returns
    -------
    logging.Logger
        The logger object.
    """
[code follows here]
```

Comment: Docstrings have no formal meaning. If you want something that can be reliably validated by static analysis tools, using type hints.

Comment: You docstring also doesn't match your example usage. For example, for `stream_logger`, neither `"active"` nor `"level"` are bools, and `True` isn't among the value choices.

Comment: @Brian61354270: This is why I said "I don't know if this is correct".

`stream_logger["active]` shall be either `True` or `False`. Hence it has a boolean value. Or am I mistaken here?
`streamer_logger["level"]` shall bei either `"debug"`, `"info"`, `"warning"`, `"error"` or `"critical"`. Hence string values.

And I don't know how to properly map this into the docstring.